# Horizontal scrolling lags on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a horizontal scrolling on a div (wrapper) and many children inside this. All works good on every browser. But when it comes to iOS the scrolling lags a lot. Any idea what is wrong?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
  <a href="" class="item">Item</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you fully understand the `webkit-overflow-scrolling`? IS that the behaviour you want? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling. This may be whats causing the inconsistent scrolling.

Comment: I like the effect of the scrolling after touch release but I will try to remove it to see if it is this how is causing this problem

Comment: What is wrong is Apple purposely downgrading your phone and tablet experience. ;-)

Comment: I did test to remove the webkit-overflow-scrolling but it did not be any better.
@JoostS I don't think that is the problem. I am testing on a iPhone X

Comment: A 1000 dollar phone that does not scroll smooth. Ouch! Just when I thought things could not get worse for Apple. ;-)

Comment: It’s not a problem with the phone this is css related. And let’s talk about the issue and not a specific phone

Comment: @AlexThomas any other ideas?

Comment: I think it’s something with tap is recognized instead on swipe